# python regex match string does not start with

Tags: python, regex

I want to match any string that **does not** start with 4321
I came about it with the positive condition: match any string that starts with 4321:

```
^4321.*
```

[regex here](https://regex101.com/r/fC1wX4/9)

Now I want to reverse that condition, for example:

- `1234555` passes
- `12322222` passess
- `None` passess
- `4321ZZZ` does not pass
- `43211111` does not pass

Please help me find the simplest regex as possible that accomplishes this.

I am using a mongo regex but the regex object is build in python so please no python code here (like `startswith`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead (needs a multiline modifier):

```
^(?!4321).*
```

You can also use a negative look-behind (doesn't match empty string for now):

```
(^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!4321).*)
```

Note: like another answer stated, regex is not required (but is given since this was the question verbatim) -> instead just use `if not mystring.startswith('4321')`.

Edit: I see you are explicitly asking for a regex now so take my first one it's the shortest I could come up with ;)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fC1wX4/10 - am I missing something? I'm getting 0 matches even though I should get 2 out of 3  here

Comment: It does match, if you add the multiline-modifier to the regex: https://regex101.com/r/fC1wX4/12

Comment: It works for me: https://regex101.com/r/qN5nM8/1 and https://regex101.com/r/hU1tO4/1

Comment: Why do you exclude empty strings?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what exactly do you mean? I am matching only strings that don't start with 4321.

Comment: Yes and an empty string doesn't start with 4321, but your patterns don't match it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: You need to fix the second pattern too. *(and add a multiline support for the two patterns)*

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regex for that. Just use `not` and the `startswith()` method:

```
if not mystring.startswith('4321'):
```

You can even just slice it and compare equality:

```
if mystring[:4] != '4321':
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you match the string, and negate the boolean value using `not`:

```
import re
result = re.match('^4321.*', value)
if not result:
    print('no match!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank, @idos. For a complete answer I used the `mongo's` $or opertator

```
mongo_filter = {'$or': [{'db_field': re.compile("^(?!4321).*$")}, {'db_field1': {'$exists': False}}]})
```

This ensure not only strings that starts with 4321 but also if the field does not exists or is `None`